# Change value of single dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropdown

I have run into a problem and I'm not sure how to get around it. I have 5 dropdown buttons, and when i select one option from the first dropdown, it changes it to that option for all 5 dropdowns.

Any help is greatly appreciated :D (p.s. I only copied 1 block of code from 1 button. also note that all 5 dropdowns are in the same  of a modal).

The function I'm trying to use to update it is

```js
$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function() {
  $("#Communityone").text($(this).text());
  $("#Communityone").val($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="Communityone" data-toggle="dropdown">Choice 1 <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="c11">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">SpeedRunner</a>
      </li>
      <p></p>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Giveaway</a>
      </li>
      <p></p>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Community</a>
      </li>
      <p></p>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Interactive</a>
      </li>
      <p></p>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Chill</a>
      </li>
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Beta</a>
      </li>
      <p></p>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">exampl</a>
      </li>
      <p></p>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">example</a>
      </li>
      <p></p>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">example</a>
      </li>
      <p></p>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">example</a>
      </li>
      <p></p>
    </div>
```

Comment: there is no input field in your code so `.val()` is no use here, should be `$("#Communityone").html($(this).text());`

Comment: You're going to lose the `<span class="caret">` when you set the text of `#Communityone`.

Comment: Unfortunetly that didnt do anything :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/txunk1Lx/2/)

```
$("div.dropdown ul li").on("click",function()
{
    $(this).parents(".dropdown").find("button").html($(this).text()+" <span class='caret'></span>");
});
```

Comment: this still makes them all the same after selected :/ https://gyazo.com/b87122a9b400d4c5507e7fedacca32dc